# Django Multi OR Operations

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I am trying to do an OR operation for a specific group without knowing the number for each so that it is more than an OR LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genres LIKE '%Action%' or genres LIKE '%Comedy%'
```

If we assume that I have genres added to it, how can I control the genre so that more than one OR can be chosen for genres without knowing how many genres will be entered?
Like Example

User input Genres: [Action, Comedy, Horror]
as we can see user add new Genres **Horror**

so, my query Muse be

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genres LIKE '%Action%' or genres LIKE '%Comedy%' or genres LIKE '%Horror%'
```

My Simple Script

```
series = series_db.objects.filter(Q(genres__icontains='Action') | Q(genres__icontains='Comedy'),
            status=1
        ).values('id','title')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `Q` object dynamically:

```
from operator import or_
from functools imoprt reduce

genres = ["Action", "Comedy", "Horror"]

q = reduce(or_, (Q(genres__icontains=g) for g in genres))
# ...
qs = qs.filter(q)
```

This is a shortcut for:

```
q = Q(genres__icontains=genres[0])
for g in genres[1:]:
    q |= Q(genres__icontains=g)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the real problem was | I don't know exactly how it can be written programmatically. This is the first time I know that
|=
it mean itself |
Thanks For answer

Comment: `q = q | Q(...)` would be equivalent and maybe a more familiar sight.